# TOST procedure + power analysis: how to interpret t-value inside bounds

Tags: t-test, p-value, statistical-power, equivalence, tost

I conducted a TOST procedure according to the guidelines by Lakens [1] and received the results from the table below. For "discontinuity", "fragmentation" and "suboptimal_luminosity", the sample size was 100 for the others it was just 50 because I had to split them in halves (the reason for that does not matter).

A power analysis resulted in a minimum reliably detectable effect size of ~0.28 for the 100-sample categories and ~0.40 for the 50-sample ones. The p-values are not significant for "discontinuity" and suboptimal_luminosity", but Cohen's D_z is fairly small for both of them. This brings me to my questions:

1. How can I interpret this Cohen's D_z value? It is obv. not a hard limit that gets checked against the equivalence bounds, since its smaller than them for insignificant tests.
2. If 0.283 ist my **minimum detectable effect size**, do effect sizes (Cohens D_z) that are smaller than that even make any sense? Can I, for example, say something along the lines of: "The TOST could not find significant evidence for equivalence, but even so, the effects are quite small so in certain cases treating them as equivalent might still be sensible"? Or to put it differently: Are effects below the minimum reliably detectable threshold from the power analysis likely just *wrong*, or are they correct, but were just unlikely to be detected?

[1] D. Lakens, A. M. Scheel, and P. M. Isager, “Equivalence Testing for Psychological Research: A Tutorial,” Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, vol. 1, no. 2, pp. 259–269, Jun. 2018, doi: 10.1177/2515245918770963.

|  | qu | half | cohen_dz | bounds | nhst_t | nhst_p | tost_t | tost_p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | noisiness | 1 | -0.017 | 0.404 | -0.117 | 0.907 | 2.741 | 0.004 |
| 1 | noisiness | 2 | -0.019 | 0.404 | -0.132 | 0.895 | 2.726 | 0.004 |
| 2 | unclearness | 1 | 0.009 | 0.404 | 0.066 | 0.948 | 2.792 | 0.004 |
| 3 | unclearness | 2 | 0.067 | 0.404 | 0.477 | 0.636 | 2.381 | 0.011 |
| 4 | discontinuity | nan | 0.12 | 0.283 | 1.196 | 0.235 | 1.633 | 0.053 |
| 5 | fragmentation | nan | 0.016 | 0.283 | 0.156 | 0.876 | 2.673 | 0.004 |
| 6 | suboptimal_luminosity | nan | 0.156 | 0.283 | 1.563 | 0.121 | 1.266 | 0.104 |